# .htaccess redirect and make pretty url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am very new to .htaccess just want to write one rule which is something like this:

`http://www.example.com/profile.php?username=John.janorkar`

Want to make it something like this:

`http://www.example.com/profile/John.janorkar`

I also want to redirect without www to www as below (below code is working fine just have problem with above one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can any expert help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```